# Route private network traffic using public ip/network

Tags: networking, linux-networking

Newbie here, [scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/422HI.png) I have 2 servers with 1 public and 1 private IP each.

```
  serverA : eth0 (54.173.62.149 | public ip)
            privateip 10.38.1.1/24

  serverB: eth1(13.33.152.13 |public ip)
           privateip 10.48.1.1/24
```

Is it possible to route the private ip traffic through public interface ? kindly provide suggestion/links on approaches for such cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't route private IPs over the public internet. RFC 1918 addresses are non-routable by definition. You need to use an IP tunnel to route private networks between public IPs.